# Is using if-else a possible substitute for try-catch exception handling mechanism

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Recently, I was studying about throwing our own exceptions and I thought that maybe we can use `if-else` to check for the "suspicious" code and then deal with it in the `if` block. In the corresponding `else` block, we may proceed as if no exception arises..

---

I know it may be a bit difficult to use an `if` statement to try catching all the exceptions but it is possible. Plus, I guess it will also be better in terms of memory usage as I have heard that `try-catch` blocks are very expensive in terms of memory usage.

Comment: I don't see how it's possible or desirable.

Comment: There exists cases where you cannot apply your if-then-else because you don't know for what to test for, for example in external (binary) libraries.

Comment: You could also use `try/catch/finally` to replace traditional flow control structures `if/else/while/for/...`.  It is not recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually in old languages there were no `try...catch` keywords and you should always use your own ways to deal with exceptions (yes, `if-else` could be used).

But today in languages like Java for example there are pieces of code where you MUST use try/catch because of checked exceptions. So depending on the language and what you are coding you can't completely stop using `try...catch` blocks.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Checked_exceptions

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the Try / Catch is that it "catches" any errors you may have missed specifically coding for.  I personally feel you should try to explicitly code for all conditions you can foresee and then use Try/Catch to handle errors you didn't foresee (and there will always be some of these).

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are handled by the JVM; it's impossible for clients to ignore a checked exception.

You can add any validation of "suspicious" code you like, but you should still use try/catch where needed.

Write the proper idiom of Java.  I see no advantage to your scheme, and it's likely to be confusing to anyone who has to maintain your code after you.  (That poor person might even be you in 6-12 months.)